# Notice "undefined index" when running MySQL query

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm new to programming. Would you kindly assist me in getting data from MySQL to a PHP list/menu?

```
<tr>
    <td align="right">Owners Name</td>
    <td>
        <select name="owners" id="owners">

            <?php 

            $owners = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['owners']);
            $sql = mysql_query("SELECT lld_Lname,lld_Fname FROM landlords "); 

            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
            {
            ?> 

            <option <?php echo $_POST['owners']==$row['owners'] ? 'selected' : ''?>><?php echo $row['owners'] ?></option> 


            <?php 
            } 
            ?> 

        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

After running the above code I get this error:

> Notice :undefined index:owners in c:\wamp\www\real_estate\admin\add_building.php online 41

Comment: As the values in $row are the column values returned by the database query, and your database query only returns the lld_Lname and lld_Fname columns, why would you expect $row['owners'] to exist?

Comment: Just include the `owners` field in your `Select` statement

Comment: If you're new to programming, be sure to start in the right place. Use PDO or MySQLi to interact with the database, not `mysql_*` which has long been deprecacted. Whatever tutorial you're following, you should probably drop it. Re question, if you're not posting `owners` to the page, you will get the same undefined index error.

Comment: Notices are not Errors. They are notices! I suggest you to work with some very basic MySQL / PHP tutorials to get a better feeling for what a `SELECT` and all this is actually doing

Comment: $sql = mysql_query("SELECT lld_Lname,lld_Fname,owners FROM landlords ");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <?php 
    $owners = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['owners']);
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT owners FROM landlords ") or die(mysql_error());
    ?>
    <tr> 
    <td align="right">Owners Name</td> 
    <td><select name="owners" id="owners">

        <?php
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) { ?> 

        <option <?php echo $_POST['owners']==$row['owners'] ? 'selected' : ''?>><?php echo $row['owners'] ?></option> 

        <?php } ?> 

        </select>
    </td>
    </tr>
```

If owners column is available in your DB table this may work or post the error you are getting

Comment: my DB table landlords has has lld_Id, lld_Lname,lld_Fname columns.Am trying to retrieve the last name and first name for the user to choose from drop down list.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

just print_r your $row and check which all data are fetched.
Check [owners] if exist or not (will be no in your case) and then proceed further with comparison

Comment: @MrCode Thanks for the advice i will sure try PDO or Mysqli